# magento get products with enabled Flat Catalog Product

Tags: magento

we would like to check if products exists with the following code:

```
$foundProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
```

We only get positive results if "Use Flat Catalog Product" is disabled in the configuration.

What's going wrong?

Kind regards,

Matthias

Comment: You should ask magento related questions on http://magento.stackexchange.com/